# How can I run this program?

Tags: python

I was looking for an origami simulation program (can simulate a piece of paper and fold) and I found the following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1TAOKIRV2d4
It looks very nice so I tried to use it... but I couldn't. and I don't why. I get the following message error:

```
ImportError: No module named visual
```

And I have python and vpython. Also I tried to change the line of code:

`import visual *` for

```
import vpython *
```

of the .py script but it wasn't effective.

Can you help me to run this program in ubuntu please? or do you know another good origami simulation program I can use in Ubuntu?

EDIT 1. According to the comment by @Dimitrios Zacharatos I typed

`pip install vpython` and got the following:

```
Command 'pip' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install python-pip
```

So I did it and again typed:

`pip install vpython`

This time at the end of the process I got the following warning:

```
jupyter-server-proxy requires Python '>=3.5' but the running Python is 2.7.17
```

Comment: did you do pip install vpython?

Comment: if you are in linux open a terminal and type pip install vpython does that work?

Comment: @DimitriosZacharatos  I edit the question adding that suggestion, but basically it did'nt work.

Comment: I wonder if you try to run it using python 2 or python 3. It makes no good to install a module in python 3 of you run this thing in python 2. I am not an expert in python but try to install these things in both python 2 and 3 pip3 install visual pip2 install visual

Comment: @DimitriosZacharatos I tried with both python 2 (and get the import message error) and python 3 (and get an error of print instead of print() ) but nothing, and I have the module installed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install and use `python3-pip`

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 install vpython
```

Comment: I typed those commands and installed successfully, but I still have the same error message: " ImportError: No module named visual" when I try to run the .py script of the program.

Comment: @JoséMarín Try running the file with: `python3 /path/to/Origami.py`

Comment: @dessert I open with python3 and got a error message this time about the calling of function print because it has to be print(). In the other hand I typed the code you just wrote: and got the error:  'python3: can't open file '/path/to/Origami.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory´